# how can I fix coa npm library 2.1.3 problem?

Tags: angular, npm

When I build Angular project, console logs:
Error: 404 Not Found - coa-2.1.3.tgz
I Don't use this library on my project(package.json), last version of this package is 2.0.2 and I can not image what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS A REFERENCE TO A MALWARE PACKAGE**. Please clean remove your `package-json.lock` and redo a `npm install`. See [Popular 'coa' NPM library hijacked to steal user passwords](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/popular-coa-npm-library-hijacked-to-steal-user-passwords/) for more detailed information

Comment: I already see this article but doesn't works

Comment: did you do a `npm cache clean -force` in addition?

Comment: Yes, I clean cache but no result

Comment: is it STILL giving the same error? Downloading coa-2.1.3??? You need to clean whatever you have from npm on your disk npm/yarn cache, package-lock.json, nodes_module folder of your project. That should wipe any reference to the stale module version

Comment: yes, I clear everything but no result. I find other way, I install my internal npm and clone coa-2.0.2 library on my new npm, after that my enterprise application doesn't has any problem

Comment: The solution for me was to specifically install the last available version which is:
  "coa": "2.0.2".

They don't update that library since 3 years ago